# Qt moveToThread slot not called

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qthread, slot

I have a class `Manager`

> ```
> class Manager : public QThread 
> {
>     Q_OBJECT
>     public:
>     Manager();
>     void run()
>     {
>         taskB = new TaskB();
>         taskA = new TaskA();
>         connect(taskA, SIGNAL(signalOk()), taskB, SLOT(onSignalOk()));
>         connect(taskA, SIGNAL(moveOk()), taskB, SLOT(onMoveOk()));
>         connect(taskB, SIGNAL(signal()), taskA, SLOT(onSignal()));
>         connect(taskB, SIGNAL(moveToThreadSignal(QThread*)), taskA, SLOT(onMoveToThread(QThread*)));
>         connect(this, SIGNAL(runSignal()), taskB, SLOT(onRun()));
>         emit runSignal();
>     }
>     TaskA* taskA;
>     TaskB * taskB;
>     signals:
>     void runSignal();
>     };
> ```

I have also the class `TaskA` like this :

> ```
> class TaskA : public QObject
> {
>     Q_OBJECT
>     public:
>     TaskA();
>     void run()
>     {
>         std::cout << "[INFO] : Task run: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
>         emit signalOk();
>     }
>     public slots:
>     void onSignal()
>     {
>         run();
>     }
>     void onMoveToThread(QThread * t)
>     {
>         std::cout << "[INFO] : Task A after move to thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
>         this->moveToThread(t);
>         std::cout << "[INFO] : Task A after move to thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
>         emit moveOk();
>     }
>     signals:
>     void signalOk();
>     void moveOk();
> };
> ```

And I have also the class `TaskB` like this

> ```
> class TaskB : public QObject
> {
>     Q_OBJECT
>     public:
>     TaskB();
>     void run()
>     {
>         std::cout << "[INFO] : TaskB run: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
>         emit signal();
>     }
>     signals:
>     void signal();
>     void moveToThreadSignal(QThread* t);
>     public slots:
>     void onSignalOk()
>     {
>         std::cout << "[INFO] : TaskB onSignalOk : " << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
>     }
>     void onMoveOk()
>     {
>         std::cout << "[INFO] : TaskB onMoveOk: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
>         run();
>     }
>     void onRun()
>     {
>         std::cout << "[INFO] : TaskB emit MoveToThreadSignal: " << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
>         thread = new QThread();
>         thread->start();
>         emit moveToThreadSignal(thread);
>     }
>     private:
>     QThread * thread;
> };
> ```

When I start the Manager with :

> Manager *_manager = new Manager();
>
> _manager->start();

the slot `onSignalOk()` of `TaskB` isn't called.

I think the problem cause is the default parameter `Qt::AutoConnection` when I connect my signal but I don't understand.

Comment: There are other issues here and you need to think about thread affinity. I recommend you start by reading this article: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: this title is misleading. There is a movetoThread inside Qt and a function you named movetoThreadSignal. Big difference.

Comment: let's take a step back. What are you trying to do ultimately? There are a lot of flaws in code above. especially `thread = new QThread();thread->start();`. What do you expect from this code?

Comment: This code is only a bench. My project is a task manager. TaskB is a task to run other task (like TaskA) in parallel.

Comment: Thanks to @Merlin069 for his comment. With this article, I corrected my Manager and it works now. Manager inherits of QObject and not QThread, then i use moveToThread.

Comment: You're welcome. I've put an answer down, so you can mark the question as answered too ;O)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest starting by not inhering from QThread; it's name is misleading as it's more of a thread manager. The only reason, in my opinion, to inherit from QThread is if you want to change how Qt manages threads.

Instead, just inherit from QObject and move the object to a new thread. This has the advantage of being able to move multiple objects to one new thread, rather than having to create a separate thread for each object if you were to inherit QThread.